# Time Zone conversions-Selecting timezones from a table and using it in TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

i wanted to learn timezone conversion 
i tried this code for timezone conversion's

```
select 
    ( TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ 
         ( TO_CHAR
             ( sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS' ) 
             || ' GMT' ,   'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS TZR' 
         ) 
    AT TIME ZONE  DECODE
        (1,1,'US/PACIFIC',2,'EUROPE/LONDON',3,'ASIA/TOKYO',4,'ASIA/CALCUTTA');
```

but instead if i try to fetch the timezone from a table instead of using the decode statement i get an error

```
select
    (TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ 
        ( TO_CHAR 
            ( sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS' ) 
            || ' GMT' , 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS TZR' 
         ) 
    AT TIME ZONE 
        (select t_zone from table where region_code=1);
```

Could you please help me understand what is the problem.

I even tried `new_time()` but still it doesnt work

Comment: oracle Sql developer. How do i embed the row value from a table between single quotes. i tried using the concat() function but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

First of all the queries you posted are missing the `FROM` clause like `FROM dual;`, so they would error anyway. Below are my results-

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ (sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR') from dual;

TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(SYSDATE,'YYYY-
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
20-AUG-20 12.13.15 PM -05:00

SQL> select from_tz(to_timestamp(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'US/Eastern') 
at time zone 'Turkey' from dual;

FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP(SYSDATE,'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
20-AUG-12 08.15.20 PM TURKEY

SQL> create table tzone (tm_zone varchar2(30));
Table created.

SQL> insert into tzone values('Turkey');

SQL> select * from tzone;

TM_ZONE
------------------------------
Turkey

SQL> select from_tz(to_timestamp(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'US/Eastern') at time zone (select tm_zone from tzone) from dual;

FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP(SYSDATE,'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
20-AUG-12 08.16.29 PM TURKEY
```